# How to use MYSQL Database on official website

Tags: mysql

In the past, I only worked with mysql database with phpmyadmin on localhost.

Now I have a official website (online, not localhost).
So do I need to download the database and put it into the webserver, for example with WinSCP?

Comment: that depends of what kind of server you have... if it's a managed www one, you don't have to, if it's some VPS or dedicated, you have to install everything yourself

Comment: its a normal www website

Comment: so you should have some control panel to create database, maybe even phpmyadmin

Comment: I have my phpmyadmin on my localhost, where i can make the databases.
My website is hosted by Hoster, I have the WinSCP Panel, where i can manage everything manually

Think its a VPS then

Comment: You need to connecto via putty or some other ssh client and install everything manually then. Is it Linux? Search for some LAMP tutorials. For example by "How to Install LAMP stack" on google.

Comment: Windows, I have XAMPP

Comment: So login into remote desktop and install servers in there.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to see, if its already installed?

Comment: If it's a windows server, you act on it as on normal Windows, via Remote Desktop. You can check there if it has it installed like you would check if you have XAMPP aready installed on your local machine.

Comment: you can tunnel with ssh (putty wiscp or direkt with workbench )